# Javascript how to split string characters into variables

Tags: javascript, string, variables, split

I am trying to split a string's characters into variables like this:

```
<script>
var string = "hello";
//After splitting:
var stringAt1 = "h";
var stringAt2 = "e";
var stringAt3 = "l";
var stringAt4 = "l";
var stringAt5 = "o";
</script>
```

Could somebody give an example of how this can be done?

Comment: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `var a = string.split(''); stringAt1=a[0]`

Comment: Thank you, please put this in an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function can be used for requirement.

> The `split()` method splits a `String` object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

*Usage*

```js
var string = "hello";
var arr = string.split('');
var stringAt1 = arr[0];
alert(stringAt1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split according to the non-word boundary `\B` (*which matches between two word characters or two non-word characters*).

```js
var string = "hello";
alert(string.split(/\B/))
```

Then assign the splitted parts to separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

In ES5 there's no other way than

```
var splitted = "abc".split("");
var char0 = splitted[0];
var char1 = splitted[1];
etc
```

In ES6 it's much easier:

```
var [char0, char1, char2] = "abc";
```